Gitlab OIDC Azure subject identifier repository reference syntax
I am trying to make use of Azure Key Vault secrets in my Gitlab CI jobs and have followed the Configure OpenID Connect in Azure to retrieve temporary credentials guide.
I have setup a federated identity as described in the guide and have successfully run jobs that can fetch secrets, as long as the jobs run on the main branch of my repository.
project_path:<mygroup>/<myproject>:ref_type:branch:ref:main
What I want to be able to do is fetch secrets in jobs that run on any branch in my repository. I'm however struggling to find the right combination in the subject identifier to be able to do so.
I've tried some combinations as listed below

"subject": "project_path:<mygroup>/<myproject>"
"subject": "project_path:<mygroup>/<myproject>:ref_type:branch"
"subject": "project_path:<mygroup>/<myproject>:ref_type:branch:ref:*"

The Gitlab documentation is quite scarce with information regarding possible values for this.
Is it possible to allow all branches or am I stuck having to add individual branches as I have done with main?

I use the same and at the moment you need to explicitely give each branches as per documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/azure/

Azure does not support wildcard matching for subjects of a conditional
role. A separate credential configuration must be created for each
branch that needs to access Azure.

